# COMException (0x80041004): Not enough memory for operation Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal report on a .NET web application. After executing the report a number of times it gives a not enough memory exception.

```
rpt = new rptMyReport();
rpt.SetDataSource(ch);
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
Session.Add("report", rpt);
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Check memory using Device Manager as application runs.  The error could be cuased by a number of factors.1) Actually running out of memory 2) Memory not being disposed at end of a report 3) An exception that triggers endless number of exceptions 4) Recursive Algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be 20 times would it? There's a limit to the number of reports it'll show. You either have to very cleverly garbage collect, end your application to reset it, or apply a registry setting to up the limit (if this is the problem, I can find the registry key to apply for you).

Comment: Take a look at this site, it explains all the registry keys: https://help.jeff-net.com/knowledgebase/article/registry-settings-and-options-for-crystal-reports

Answer (score 0):

I added the OnUnload event and then it worked fine.

```
protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rpt != null)
        {
            rpt.Close();
            rpt.Dispose();
        }
        base.OnUnload(e);
    }
```

Comment: Force closing and disposing the report object while a reference to it is stored in the Session would cause an exception subsequently. So, you'd want to ensure it's not stored in the session or ensure that sessions are short-lived enough not to eat up all the web server memory. C# is a garbage collected language and removing the last reference to an object will cause the memory to be released when GC occurs next.